# Failed to deploy laravel in cPanel

Tags: laravel

I created laravel 5.8 project and it works perfect in localhost.. Now when I uploaded to cpanel and tried to access through internet it gives me these errors

**http://learnme.web.id/**

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@learnme.web.id to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: First read the error log, it's probably in your `public_html` directory. Second check your site structure, you should put the content of your `public` directory (in your local environment) in the `public_html` directory on the server. Other files and directories should be beside the `public_html` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you were running the appliation in the localhost with `php artisan serve`. Not with xamp or anything as such.

So here are my possible solutions

1. For laravel project to run the domain root directory should point to `public` directory of the application. Check if you have that in your cPanel, if not then point the root directory to the application public folder
2. If you are using shared hosting and you do not have permission for making such change then you might need to move the `index.php` inside the public folder to the outside of the public folder and you need to change the directory links in `bootstrap.php` file
3. Check if your all vendor files are installed and `.env` file is set properly with database connection if you are using and the application key is set.
4. You can check the server error logs for more information to dig down to the root cause of the issue